# Invalid/Expired token Error Twitter Sharekit iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

I just started getting this error when trying to share via twitter in sharekit. Everything was working fine some days back. Tried to recreate tokens, consumer key, secret key but with no success. Tried adding a new app from scartch in twitter but that too didn't help. tried changing api version from 1.0 to 1.1 but no help. What could i be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to==> https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16443

**Garrett** states that,

"During the oauth/**access_token** request, you MUST pass **oauth_verifier** now. Switch seems to have been flipped in the last 2 days. From the docs, though, it seems this shouldn't be required yet:

For OAuth 1.0a compliance this parameter is required unless you are using 
xAuth.Currently Twitter supports both OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 1.0a which means we do not error 
if this value isn't included. It is strongly recommended that applications not using this parameter are immediately updated with support for oauth_verifier added. OAuth 1.0a will be enforced soon and applications not using the oauth_verifier will fail to complete the OAuth flow.

So even though it says "will be enforced soon" it turns out soon is NOW. I added the verifier and it worked."

**UPDATE** : https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3973 refer this...

Answer (score 0):

Update sharekit. If you are using old sharekit from getsharekit.com, try updated [ShareKit 2](http://github.com/sharekit/sharekit).